# Using MinGW to compile 32-bit modern applications on Windows

Tags: winapi, compilation, mingw-w64, 32-bit, toolchain

I wish to use MinGW to compile a 32-bit application from source that contains c++20. Thus, apparently OG MinGW won't cut it due to compiler support for modern C++, but I instead need to use MinGW-w64.

Try as I may, I cannot seem to get a working MSys that can locate the 32-bit version of MinGW-w64.

I have installed `mingw-w64-i686-toolchain`, but neither `/bin` nor `/usr/bin` seem to contain an appropriate GCC executable (I was looking for `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` but nothing remotely similar was present). I'm assuming I need another command, but have tried google and stack overflow for hours with no inkling of what that might be.

What is the appropriate package to install in MSys and the appropriate name of the GCC executable?

Also, do I need to be in the `MSYS2`, `MINGW32`, or `MINGW64` shell, or doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have installed `mingw-w64-i686-toolchain`, but neither `/bin` nor `/usr/bin` seem to contain an appropriate GCC executable (I was looking for `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` but nothing remotely similar was present).

MSYS2 store MSYS2 tools and mingw-w64 tools under different paths. This means you would have no luck trying to find native compilers under `/bin` nor `/usr/bin`; instead, you should be able to find tools targeting i686 under `/mingw32/bin`, and tools targeting AMD64 under `/mingw64/bin` or `/ucrt64/bin`.

> Also, do I need to be in the `MSYS2`, `MINGW32`, or `MINGW64` shell, or doesn't it matter?

You should use the `MINGW32` shell to compile for an i686 Windows target.

The w64 part of mingw-w64 is slightly misleading; while it adds the ability to target AMD64, the ability to target i686 is not removed.